# Show two norms are equivalent

Tags: normed-spaces

> Let $$N(z)=\Bigg(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg|\frac{c_n}{n}\bigg|^3\Bigg)^{1/3}$$ be a norm on $\ell^3$ where $z=(c_n)_{n\geq1} \in \ell^3.$
>   Are the norms $N(\cdot)$ and $\|\cdot\|_3$ equivalent?

I know that the definition of equivalent norms means that I must show that:
$$aN(\cdot) \leq \|\cdot\|_3 \leq bN(\cdot)$$ for some constants $a,b>0$ but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Try to look at the usual generating elements $e_n=(0,0,\ldots,1,0,\ldots)$ and compare their norms.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro What will this tell me? If the norms are different does this mean that the norms are not equivalent? I have read somewhere about checking convergence? I'm really unsure on the method

Comment: Did you compute $N(e_n)$ and $\|e_n\|_3$? You know, before asking what-ifs and being unsure...

Comment: @Did I got $N(e_n)=\frac{1}{n}$ and $\|e_n\|_3=1$. Assuming I've done this part right, $N(e_n)$ will converge to 0 as n tends to infinity whereas $\|e_n\|_3$ won't converge. Do they both have to converge to be equivalent?

Comment: Again lost in what-ifs... Now that you have each $N(e_n)$ and each $\|e_n\|_3$, what can you say about $a$ and $b$ such that $aN(e_n)\leqslant\|e_n\|_3\leqslant bN(e_n)$ for some $n$? For every $n$ simultaneously? (See how I am merely copying parts of your question...)

Comment: @Did $a \leq n$ and $b \geq n$ for the inequality to hold. But $n$ increases to infinity, so $a$ and $b$ would not be constant. Hence, the norms are not equivalent?

Comment: Sorry but you should be more careful: I pretend that I can find some nonzero $a$ such that $a\leqslant n$ for every $n$ simultaneously. Can you? Then $a$ is not a problem, right? Now, turn to $b$...

Comment: @Did We can let $a=1$ since $n \geq 1$. $b$ needs to be greater than or equal to $n$ for all $n$, but $1 \leq n \leq \infty$. Letting $b=\infty$ does not satisfy the condition that $b$ needs to be a constant, so we cannot find $b$.

Comment: Indeed. Do not hesitate to post a solution to your own question, this practice is actually recommended.